# Dingo/Api and JWT auth

Tags: laravel, jwt, dingo-api

I'm looking for the way to implement auth with JWT and Dingo/Api. I've added JWT package to my project. Added `'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT',` into my `api.php` auth part.

And also added into my BaseController

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('api.auth');
    }
```

How do I check if the user has permission (by role) using FormRequest? It has an `authorize` method, however I'm not sure how to get my user.

Since I'm using JWT the token is sent in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to adding the role validation to the middleware.

You can try adding this custom validation to the part where it verifies the JWT the user gave as that is the part where you can determine who is the user that owns the token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Auth` Facade to retrieve the currently authenticated user:

```
$user = \Auth::user()
```

For authorization you can use policies, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization
Once enabled you can check for a users ability in your `authorize` method(s), e.g.

```
public function authorize() {
    $user = \Auth::user();
    return $user->can("do-something");
}
```

But there are multiple possibilities how to perform authorization checks, read the docs mentioned above for more details.